# Read one string at a time from a file in C

Tags: c, io

How do I read input one string at a time to call another function in C.  I thought this would work, but my output hangs:

```
#define BUFFMT "%255"
#define LINE_LEN 256
#define START_COUNT 1

// filename is declared in the main file elsewhere.  I know the file opens since I tried an //old method I use to read one line at time using fgets, but I didn't know how to do one //string at a time.  Thanks.
FILE *OpenFile(const char *fileName)
{
    FILE *fptr;
    if ((fptr = fopen(fileName, "r")) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error opening file %s, exiting...",  fileName);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return fptr;
}

LIST *CreateList(FILE *fp) 
{
    char buf[LINE_LEN];

    while (scanf(BUFFMT"s", buf) != EOF) {
        printf("%s: \n", buf);
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you call those functions in the main program?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`scanf()` is going to read from the terminal, so it's going to hang waiting for you to type in your input. Use `fscanf(fp, BUFFMT"s", buf)` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead of your scanf:

```
fgets (buf, sizeof (buf), fp)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `fgets()`

[fgets()](http://people.cs.uchicago.edu/~iancooke/osstuff/ccc.html)

> fgets() reads up to size-1 characters
>   from stream and stores them in buffer.
>   fgets() stores the null character
>   ('\0') after the last character read
>   into the buffer and returns 'buffer'
>   if everything works fine, or NULL on
>   error or end of file.